# Re-Parenting Vs Re-naming in TFS?

Tags: tfs

I am trying to understand the advantages of re-parenting option in TFS. Which one is the best approach between Re-Parenting and Re-naming  here?

Say I have,

[image]

Option A - Renaming: renaming the current parent(Release1.0) as main and creating a branch from TeamA through TeamC under Release1.0 branch and decommissioning actual Main Parent branch.

[image]

Option B - Reparenting: reparenting TeamD...G branches to main and decommissioning Release1.0 branch.

[image]

What are the pros and cons between Reparenting and Renaming branches? How about relative path references? Is it same effort between the both approach?

Answer (score 1):

Its **not recommend to rename a branch**. When you Rename a branch in Source Control, it will **delete the previous one and create a new one**. Even though the hierarchy is all the same , but the branch is tollay different. For instance, once renamed, tracking a changeset is a real challenge in your Branching hierarchy view. When you tracking a changeset in your child branch such as TeamD, it's in the hierarchy with the new renamed main branch. But it will also shows the associate with old Release1.0 branch by dotted line.

So suggest you to use the second option after comparing both. And here is a blog telling you more detailed info [Reparent of a TFS Source Controlled Branch. Why and How !](http://roadtoalm.com/2012/09/19/reparent-of-a-source-controlled-branch-why-and-how/)